# Not assignable to type issue

Tags: angular, object, selected

I have a problem with this tutorial I downloaded. On this.games[{ it produces and error. The errror says:

> Type '[{ game: string; platform: string; release: string; }, { game:
>   string; platform: string; release:...' is not assignable to type '[{
>   game: string; platform: string; release: string; }]'.  Types of
>   property 'length' are incompatible.  Type '6' is not assignable to
>   type '1'.

What does error mean? How can I fix it? 
Some context the tutorial is for highlighting a selected cell of a table.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    headMessage : string;
    selectedRow : Number;
    setClickedRow : Function;
    games : [{
        game: string,
        platform : string,
        release : string
    }];

    constructor(){
        this.headMessage = "Please click below rows !!";

        this.games =[{
            game : "Deus Ex: Mankind Divided",
            platform: " Xbox One, PS4, PC",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Amplitude",
            platform: " PS4",
            release : "January 5"
        },
        {
            game : "The Huntsman: Winter's Curse",
            platform: "PS4",
            release : "August 23"
        },
        {
            game : "Resident Evil Zero HD Remaster",
            platform: "Win, PS3, PS4, X360, XBO",
            release : "January 19"
        },
        {
            game : "Lego Marvel's Avengers",
            platform: "Win, X360, XBO, PS3, PS4, PSVita, WiiU, 3DS",
            release : "January 26"
        };

        this.setClickedRow = function(index){
            this.selectedRow = index;
        }]
    };
};
```

Comment: In that code you're trying to assign`this.setClickedRow` within where you define your array...

Comment: That's fixed one issue but the issue specified is still a concern

Comment: Okay, Im not able to reproduce it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvdbxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts Can you try creating a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue please?